# Awk command - Check for pattern and display next line of pattern in output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

Question ::

I have a log file which contains information like below (more than 200 ERROR sets). 
Here I want to find first .c file and function after "ERROR: AddressSanitizer" line.

If you see here after "ERROR:" line first

- file - asfrecohandling.c
- function - ASFPotRecoHandling_Create_RecPaxSrvcComp

Answer ::

```
awk '/ERROR: AddressSanitizer/ {L = 1} L && /\.c/ {print "file:", $5; print "function:", $4; L = 0}' file
file: ../Sources/ASFServices_Process/C/asfrecohandling.c:1431
function: ASFPotRecoHandling_Create_RecPaxSrvcComp
```

Log ::

```
=================================================================
==10073==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x7f5941fe08c0 at pc 0x7f5ed5d37de8 bp 0x7fffe6927310 sp 0x7fffe6927308
READ of size 4 at 0x7f5941fe08c0 thread T0
    #0 0x7f5ed5d37de7 in ASFPotRecoHandling_Create_RecPaxSrvcComp ../Sources/ASFServices_Process/C/asfrecohandling.c:1431
    #1 0x7f5ed5d2ef50 in ASFPotRecoHandling ../Sources/ASFServices_Process/C/asfrecohandling.c:399
```

I see few logs have .cpp files also. Now I want to check either .c or .cpp file in first line with above same command. I tried with && and || as well but no luck

```
#0 0x7f5ed5d37de7 in ASFPotZXZXoHandling_KJT_RecPBVBVrvcComp ../Sources/ASFServices_Process/C/asfrecohandling.cpp:1431
#1 0x7f5ed5d2ef50 in ASFPotRecoHandling ../Sources/ASFServices_Process/C/asfrecohandling.c:399
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add samples with CODE TAGS clearly too in your post.

Comment: So is the line with the c/cpp-file immediately in the next line, and only looks as second line, due to too long lines, being wrapped, or is it in one of the next lines, any you just want to get the content from the first of them?

Answer (score -1):

The basic difference is, to look for cpp and c in one command with:

```
/\.c(pp)?/
```

The question mark says 'optional' and the braces say, that not only the last p is optional, but the combination of both.

I would probably use a stricter regex:

```
/[ \t]#[0-9]+.*[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.c(pp)?:[0-9]+/
```

This grabs for the following colon and line number, and for the source file name, which has to - if I remember correctly, conform to identifier restrictions, and begins with whitespaces, hash mark and an stack number.

```
awk '/ERROR: AddressSanitizer/ {L = 1} L && /[ \t]#[0-9]+.*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.c(pp)?:[0-9]+/ {print "file:", $5; print "function:", $4; L = 0}' asan.err
```